# How to pass array by reference in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm using `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)`. How can I pass an array by reference to another function. I need to modify global array from function.

Let's say I have

```
arr=('apples' 'oranges' 'bananas')

function modifyArray(){
   increment=1
   newArray=()
   declare -n inputArray="$1"
   for fruits in "${inputArray[@]}"
   do
      newArray+=("$increment $fruits")
      (( ++increment ))
   done
   inputArray=("${newArray[@]}")
}

modifyArray arr
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

I get this error:

```
declare: -n: invalid option
```

Comment: You should be calling `modifyArray` with the array **name** as argument, like this `modifyArray arr`, and `declare -n inputArray="$1"` inside the function

Comment: If you [edit] your question to replace `newArray=()
   # code to create new modified array and save it in newArray` in your code with `newArray=('foo' 'bar')` then you'll have provided an example we could test with and would have saved yourself some typing.

Comment: @Fravadona I've updated my initial code with some more detail and your suggestion, however, I'm still getting the same error 'invalid option' on the line where I add 'declare'

Comment: the `-n` option was introduced in bash 4.3; you say that you're using bash 5.1 but it doesn't seem so

Comment: @Fravadona 'bash --version' shows 5.1.16 'which bash' shows correct folder '/usr/local/bin/bash'. The old (3.2) bash is installed in '/bin/bash' folder

Comment: Does `echo $BASH_VERSION` _within the script during execution_ show proper bash version?

Comment: add the shebang `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` as the first line of your script

Comment: @Fravadona yes, the shebang is correct... I just tried '/usr/local/bin/bash' instead of 'sh' while running bash file and it worked. 'sh' is still linked to old bash, how can I re-link it to new bash

Comment: As your using bashisms in your script, running it with `sh` shall always fail

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
arr=('white' 'red' 'orange')
modifyArray() { increment=1; newArray=(); declare -n inputArray="$1"; for fruits in "${inputArray[@]}"; do newArray+=("$increment $fruits"); (( ++increment )); done; inputArray=("${newArray[@]}"); }
modifyArray arr
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

Above works
If you still have problem
Below link has an answer about referecing array to a function

https://askubuntu.com/questions/674333/how-to-pass-an-array-as-function-argument